# External Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Let's keep this short and sweet.

Here is my header:

```
<head>
    <title>4JSB Assignment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/form.js"></script>
</head>
```

Note: `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/form.js"></script>`

Does not appear to be working.

I have a Submit button in the body that is part of a form. Here it is, located at the end of the aforementioned form:

```
<input type=submit name="submitForm" id="submitForm" onclick="submitForm()">
```

Here is my external javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
alert("Working");
}
```

Alas, "Working" never appears.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
root
    css
    ....style.css

    javascript
    ....form.js

    form.html
```

The answer is more than likely trivial, but has had me stuck on this assignment for hours because of this one requirement that the javascript be linked from an outside source. I appreciate any attempt to point out this mundane and unfortunate mishap to me.

Comment: check the network tab of your browsers developer tools - is form.js loading? also, if you're using IE/Edge it's particularly annoying when using javascript if the page is loaded using file:/// protocol

Comment: go through the page click right button and "click view page source".Then click `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/form.js"></script>` and check is this ok or not?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have `id="submitForm"` and `function submitForm`

Not sure why browsers do this, but any id is available as a global object

so,

```
console.log(submitForm);
```

would show the input element, rather than the function!!

use a different name for the id, or for the function

> `console.log(submitForm)` actually shows the function!! but it's still a name conflict in the end.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks very much.

Comment: Whit that change, does your form actually submit?

Comment: there was nothing in the question about submit/no submit, so it's a cows opinion

Comment: I didnt downvote your question so stop the witch hunting. I guessing @JosiasMenzel want to submit the form otherwise why the use of a submit button??

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name and id of your submit button to something like "submitButton" so that it isn't exactly the same as your javascript function. I believe there is a name conflict.

Comment: Did exactly this when Jaromanda commented about the id issue. It is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you want to acomplish:

If you add a onclick function on your submit button it wont work for submit the form, so it will be pointless to have it as that.

If you want execute a javascript function before submit the form and or want to perform some validations that may or may not prevent the form for being submitted . **The best way** to  do it:

```
<form onsubmit="return submitform();">
    ....
    <input type=submit name="submitFormAny" id="submitFormAny">
</form>
```

Also as other contributors were saying, be careful, you can't have elements and functions with same id's